# Keycloak set different user roles based on location

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak

Scenario is there are two retail shops in two cities in the country that share one keycloak instance running in cloud.
We have one web application for managing shop activites and employees with different positions, but limited to the shop where they work.

Assume, for simplicty to have two different roles:  Shop Manager and Seller.
We would like that an employee for a given shop can access via the web portal to the data belonging just to its own shop based on his role, not to the other shop data.

Right now the only way we found to manage this is to actually have a separate database where we keep track of each user-id to which shops it belongs, but we were thinking if it's possible to manage this directly via keycloak, having the capability to say: "Jim is Manager for shop 1, and nothing for shop 2".
No idea if this is actually possible via scopes or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate your roles by groups via a group hierarchy. For example, you may create a hierarchy like that:

```
/Shop1/Manager
/Shop1/Seller

and

/Shop2/Manager
/Shop2/Seller
```

Then you can add groups to access or/and id token via a group membership mapper.